# javascript object scope and performance

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I am new in JavaScript . 
I dont know which one code block better than other (base on performance) . 
I have been recently learning JavaScript opps since one month .

Working around the nested function issue by leveraging the scope chain

```
var myObject = {
myProperty: 'I can see the light',
myMethod : function(){
    var that = this; // store a reference to this (i.e. myObject) in myMethod scope
    var helperFunction = function() { // child function
    // logs 'I can see the light' via scope chain because that = this
    console.log(that.myProperty); // logs 'I can see the light'
    //console.log(this); // logs window object, if we don't use "that"
    }();
}
}
myObject.myMethod(); // invoke myMethod



var myObject = (function(wn){

  return {

    myProperty: 'I can see the light',
    myMethod : function(){

      var helperFunction = function() { 
        console.log(wn.myObject.myProperty); // logs 'I can see the light'

      }();
    }
  }

}(this));
myObject.myMethod(); // invoke myMethod
```

Comment: So what is the question? What's wrong with the first example?

Comment: Thank you sir for quick reply

Asking base on performance ....

Comment: The first one might be faster. But do not care, were talking about 1/100 ms ...

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) or any other benchmarking site. It compares the snippets based on how often they are executed in a certain amount of time. The first one is certainly cleaner, as it doesn't rely on the global scope.

Comment: @PeterMader Microbenchmarks are useless, because they only test how good the JS engine can optimize the testcode. And that may be completely unrelated to how JS optimizes the very same piece of code in a real world application; and its performance there.

Comment: performance is no topic at all in this comparison. The biggest impact on performance in these codes has the creation of the useless/obsolete `helperFunction`, just to immediately call it. But I dislike the second approach, because it introduces another source of error: your object depends on the global reference `window.myObject` to reference `this`. If this may ever change you'll have to fix every place you used `wn.myObject`. If you miss a spot, you've introduced a bug. Better introduce a variable inside the closure to reference the object.